# Why am I losing rings in Oil Ocean Zone Act 2?

Tags: sonic-mania

In Oil Ocean Zone Act 2, the screen keeps getting dark and smoky as I play the level. As the smog gets thicker, the ring meter starts flickering rapidly, making me lose rings at a constant pace.

[image: Losing rings from smog]

Is there a way to clear the air so I stop losing rings?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**There are chain switches throughout the level which will temporarily clear the air.**

Based on the in-game timer, you will have about 30 seconds to find another chain switch before you start to lose rings again.

The smog cannot kill you directly, as the ring-draining effect will stop if the player hits 0 rings.

[image: Sonic clearing the air with a switch]

**Interesting side note**: The chain-pulling mechanic is a callback to Sandopolis Zone Act 2 from Sonic 3 & Knuckles, which had the same chains acting as temporary light-switches.

[image: Sonic 3 - Sandopolis Zone light switch]